# Memory pointers: modifying dataframes in python pandas

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, pandas, dataframe

supposed I have an `n x n` dataframe `d1` in pandas. I then take a subset of `d1` and create another dataframe that is `m x m` where `m < n`, call it `d2`. When I modify `d2`, I want those same changes to appear in the "parent" dataframe, `d1`. Thus I want `d2` to just be a memory pointer to that subset of `d1`. How would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work reliably, it'd be better to just use a variable that defined the slice ranges/indices/mask and use this to reference back to the original df

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Ed if you are going to do stuff in pandas.  You do have more control over this sort of thing if you can keep things in numpy though, which might be a decent alternative for you if you have homogeneous data (e.g. all floats and you don't mind referring to columns by location rather than label)

Comment: And to briefly elaborate on prior comment, you might be able to pull this off in pandas with homogeneous data (b/c to some degree that implies a pointer/reference rather than copy),  it's just that this is not something you can reliably count on, so be prepared for that, and use numpy if you want more reliable/predictable behavior in this respect.

Comment: @EdChum The thing is that `d2` can contain rows from `d1` that are not consecutive i.e. `d2` can be composed of rows 1-4, 10, 34-56, 65. I will consider you r suggestion @JohnE and explore numpy a bit more. Thanks

Comment: You'd have to expand the ranges to generate a list/array of all index values, you can then pass to `loc`